# VBA code to change label of multiple ribbon buttons on running a macro

Tags: excel, vba, label, ribbon

I have used the spreadsheet provided [here](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/step-by-step-instructions-create-first-excel-ribbon-vba-addin) to create a ribbon and it worked great as long as it was all about assigning macros to the buttons. However, I wanted to include configuration details in a group of the tab to make it visible all the time without consuming excel sheet real estate. Here is the to-be state:
[Group in the custom tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oYwR.jpg)

I have a small macro to select environment and identify the values of various fields shown in the image. Here is what the code looks like:

```
Sub Change_Configuration() 
    Dim ConfigButton As Object 
    Dim Labeling As String 
     'SelectEnvironment.Show
    Environment = "PROD" 
    If Environment = "QAS" Then 


        SourceSystem = "ABC" 
        TargetSystem = "DEF" 
        SourceSchema = "EFG" 
        TargetSchema = "GHI" 
    ElseIf Environment = "PROD" Then 
        SourceSystem = "IJK" 
        TargetSystem = "JKL" 
        SourceSchema = "LMN" 
        TargetSchema = "NOP" 
    End If 
    GetLabel ConfigButton, Labeling 'I do not know what to do here
End Sub
```

I know that Get Label is the way to do it but I just do not have any clue as to how to achieve what I want to achieve. My current GetLabel callback works fine when I open the excel file and populates default values correctly (The IF part). I tried to include "Else" part to update label but it just does not work.

Original Code:

```
Sub GetLabel(ByVal control As IRibbonControl, ByRef Labeling)
    Select Case control.ID

      Case "CustomTab": Labeling = "TEST_RIBBON"

      Case "GroupE": Labeling = "Configuration Details"
      Case "eButton01": Labeling = "Change Environment"
      Case "eButton02": Labeling = "Selected Environment" & " - " & "QAS"
      Case "eButton03": Labeling = "Source System" & " - " & "ABC"
      Case "eButton04": Labeling = "Source Schema" & " - " & "DEF"
      Case "eButton05": Labeling = "Target System" & " - " & "GHI"
      Case "eButton06": Labeling = "Target Schema" & " - " & "IJK"

    End Select
 End Sub
```

When I open the excel, all labels have values as defined above.

Below is the Modified code (unsuccessful effort to modify to change the label based on Change_Configuration Macro). Please note that modified code also does not throw any error when my workbook is opened and displays values correctly.

```
Sub GetLabel(ByVal control As IRibbonControl, ByRef Labeling) 


    If Environment = vbNullString Then 


        Select Case control.ID 

        Case "CustomTab": Labeling = "My Tab" 


        Case "GroupE": Labeling = "Configuration Details" 
        Case "eButton01": Labeling = "Change Environment" 
        Case "eButton02": Labeling = "Selected Environment" & " - " & "QAS" 
        Case "eButton03": Labeling = "Source System" & " - " & "ABC" 
        Case "eButton04": Labeling = "Source Schema" & " - " & "DEF" 
        Case "eButton05": Labeling = "Target System" & " - " & "EFG" 
        Case "eButton06": Labeling = "Target Schema" & " - " & "GHI" 

        End Select 

    Else 
        Select Case ConfigButton 
        Case "eButton02": Labeling = "Selected Environment" & " - " & Environment 
        Case "eButton03": Labeling = "Source System" & " - " & SourceSystem 
        Case "eButton04": Labeling = "Source Schema" & " - " & SourceSchema 
        Case "eButton05": Labeling = "Target System" & " - " & TargetSystem 
        Case "eButton06": Labeling = "Target Schema" & " - " & TargetSchema 
        End Select 
    End If 

End Sub
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

-Jevich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it - Had to include onload call back for Ribbon after adjusting XML and then Invalidate function.

Answer (score 0):

too little relevant code to be sure to help you through

but try just changing:

```
Select Case ConfigButton
```

to:

```
Select Case control.ID
```

and watch what happens...

Comment: Thanks for your response but I did try that. It goes to debugging with error is " Run time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Select Case control.ID

Comment: does it work in the `If Environment = vbNullString Then` branch?

Comment: No, it does not. I have given the link of the file that I have used. This If-Then-Else was something that I wrote to incorporate an additional check. The tab gets loaded when file is opened. I think you will get the idea if you refer the link I have shared.

Comment: the link gets me to mostly blackened screenshots. update your post with minimal functioning code reproducing both the good behavior and the bad one

Comment: the _original_ code has `Select Case control.ID`, too. Does it work there?

Comment: Yes. I think that is only triggered when the file is opened. I tried to use the callback macro to see if I can change the labels. I just followed the instructions provided here and downloaded the template. The link is http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/step-by-step-instructions-create-first-excel-ribbon-vba-addin

Comment: sorry, that link has to me mostly blackened screenshots

Comment: Okay..best I can do is to share my file with you. I have commented entire Modified code in the workbook but have kept it for your reference. File is available here - https://ufile.io/df710 hope this helps.